# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: css

I just started reading the book and trying to implement some of the CSS code. Whenever I try to create a new CSS file or open a css file, I get the following error:
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Can anyone tell me what this means and how to fix it?

Tankx.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to open or create any .css file. The problem was solved after I installed CSS3 Intellisense Schema from [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210).